# How to get Microsoft HTML Help 2 Compiler?

Tags: documentation-generation, sandcastle, html-help

Where can I download the Microsoft HTML Help 2 compiler (or bounding SDK)? I want to generate HTML 2 documentation from my programming projects using [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) and the Sandcastle Guided Installation wizard is instructing me to download that component.

Excerpt about HTML 2 taken from Sandcastle main page:

> The HTML Help 2.x output includes a
>   valid set of collection files and an
>   H2Reg.exe configuration file to
>   simplify deployment and integration of
>   the help file into existing
>   collections such as those used by
>   Visual Studio.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The HTML Help 2 compiler is **available from Microsoft in the [Visual Studio 2008 SDK 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=30402623-93ca-479a-867c-04dc45164f5b&displaylang=en) download**.
*(You shouldn't need to have Visual Studio 2008 IDE installed to have these SDK tools.)*

Apparently the file needed is ***hxcomp.exe***

After installation of the SDK (on x64 system) the needed file was installed here and the Sandcastle Wizard found it.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Help 2.0 Compiler\hxcomp.exe
```

On an x86 system it would be found under the regular `Program Files` folder name.

---

### Addendum Notes: About tracking down the answer, etc:

According to a CodePlex Sandcastle Help File Builder forum post:

> So I checked my installation, and it
>   appears that I don't have HXCOMP.EXE
>   installed on my machine anywhere. 
>   According to [this article](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman-faqs/where-can-i-download-hxcompexe.html), it's only
>   in version 1.0 of the VS 2008 SDK.  I
>   have Visual Studio 2008 installed.
>   -- http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/212256

The article referenced in the above post mentions:

> **Where can I download HxComp.exe?**
>
> - **VS 2010** doesn't use MS Help2  format so ***there is no Help2
>     compiler available for it***. Starting
>     with VS 2010, the new MS Help Viewer
>     format is used
> - For **VS 2008** hxcomp.exe is a part of VS 2008 SDK version 1.0. Note, the
>     latest version VS 2008 SDK doesn't
>     contain hxcomp.exe, so you need to
>     install version 1.0! It is probably
>     possible to install version 1.0 and
>     then the latest version over it.
> - For **VS 2005** hxcomp.exe is a part of VS 2005 SDK.
> - For **VS .NET 2003** hxcomp.exe is a part of VSHIK 2003.
> - For **VS .NET 2002** hxcomp.exe is a part of VSHIK 2002 (Visual Studio Help
>     Integration Kit v2.1).
>
> -- Excerpted from http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman-faqs/where-can-i-download-hxcompexe.html

Although I found the solution by installing the recommended VS 2008 SDK 1.0, you might use one of the alternate sources listed in the points.

Comment: Just to clear that out: In my case the VS 2008 SDK complained about the absence of VS 2008 IDE on my machine. But there is a trick: Download the SDK, go inside it using a tool like 7Zip and opy out cssdk.msi and vssdk.cab into for example the desktop. Then run the msi directly. This will skip the prereq-check.

Comment: 7-zip wouldn't extract those files for me, but while the exe was running, they were available in a hashed folder directly under C:\  where I was able to copy them to the side and skip the pre-req check.  Note however then I ran into an issue with a requirement on MSHelp 2.0 being installed.  This page has more details on: http://www.helpware.net/mshelp2/h20.htm